# MVC .NET Guid model view submission as input hidden

Tags: c#, .net, razor, model-view-controller, guid

Do anyone know a way to submit a form that own's a GUID as input type hidden.
Kind of:

```
public class DummyModelView
 {
    public Guid guid {set; get;}
 }
```

View:

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.guid)
```

Is there a way to controller receive this info such like:

```
public ActionResult GetGuidSubmission(DummyModelView view) {
  .....
}
```

Comment: it should work out of the box, did you try it? what is the problem, you receive null?

Comment: Exactly. I thought the same way, but somehow the values not bind the model.

Comment: Could you share the code for your view (the entire form)?

Comment: Did you try to check the value of guid in htmp (view source)?

Comment: Sorry stupidity, i had Html.hidden instead of hiddenfor and didn't match the names in view and model. 
Now i have the parameters ok.